# Feature/shapefile does not show up in Python

Tags: python, cartopy

This is the code I have

```
fname = r"C:\Users\Kevin Abbot\Documents\W&OD Trail.shp"
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(fname).geometries(),
                                ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature,zorder=10)
```

When I plot the map it shows nothing

Here is the code for the plot (note a lot of things are commented out

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24,20),facecolor='white')

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
#ax.set_extent([leftlon, rightlon, botlat, toplat]) ## Important
#ax.coastlines(zorder=0, facecolor='grey')
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN,zorder=3, facecolor='teal')
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES,zorder=3, facecolor='teal')
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE,zorder=0, facecolor='grey')
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES,zorder=0, facecolor='grey')
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES,zorder=10, edgecolor='midnightblue')
fname = r"C:\Users\Kevin Abbot\Documents\W&OD Trail.shp"
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(fname).geometries(),
                                ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature,zorder=10)

####FrzRain#
"""
plt.tricontourf(c['lon'], c['lat'], c['index'],levels = 30, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='brg_r', zorder=2)
cbar = plt.colorbar(extend='neither', spacing='proportional',
                orientation='horizontal', shrink=1, format="%.0f")
cbar.set_label(r"Cycling Conditions", size=30)
cbar.set_ticks([0,15,22,30,38,50,60])
cbar.set_ticklabels(["Ideal Conditions","Slightly Unpleasent","Uncomfortable","Rough","Nearly Unridable","Unridable","Dangerous"])
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
"""
plt.savefig(r"FDMVARIF.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

I manually add the same shapefile to arcgis pro and it loads in fine.. I don't know why it wont load in python. It is just a trail path so just a jagged line.

Comment: Try using `geopandas` which simplifies reading in the files and has a plotting function. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html

Comment: Does your code produce an error? Side note: when you code it's best not to use spaces in your file names/paths. Use underscores or dashes (I've been told underscores are best, since dashes can be read as 'minus').

Answer (score 0):

```
import geopandas as gpd

fname = r"C:\Users\Kevin Abbot\Documents\W&OD Trail.shp"

shapefile = gpd.read_file(fname)

shapefile.plot(color="blue", figsize=(5,5))
```